# Need help identifying component on circuit board

Tags: circuit-analysis, identification

I need help identifying these components. Any help would be appreciated. I have an r12 amplifier for a VW Passat 2012 Fender sound system.

Attached is a picture of all the serial numbers the pair of black boxes with a line that goes down it and is inscribed `SC 1A` and has a symbol perhaps a switched capacitor? Maybe `SG 1A`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Surface-Mount Glass Passivated Rectifier or a diode.
I found this link based on the initials and they seem similar : https://www.vishay.com/docs/88711/s1.pdf

Comment: It's a Vishay S1GHE3_A/H, see [here](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Diodes-General-Purpose_Vishay-Intertech-S1GHE3_A-H_C511020.html).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in previous answers it's a diode from Vishay (General semdiconductor logo).

However I would say that the package is a SMC (wide aspect).

So the corresponding part number for that marking is [S3G (datasheet)](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88713/s3a.pdf).
Moreover, you mentionned that it is assembled on a VW car. I would suggest you to use the S3GHM3* part number. (HM3 suffix is the automotive qualified version).

[image]